# Control XML element name dynamically during serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

here's my problem to be solved: I've a plugin-structure for multimedia shows that allows to implement media types in external assemblies by subclassing from a base class in my framework. A show holds a list of media types. Shows are loaded and saved in XML using the `XmlSerializer`. This all works, even with programatic type mapping for plugin MediaTypes.

However, I want to be able to load XML files that contain MediaTypes **that are not known**, because the plugin isn't available.

For illustration, here is such an XML file:

```
<MultiMediaShow>
    <MediaTypes>
        <SomeType />
        <SomeType />
        <AnotherType />
        <UnknownTypeFromPluginNotLoaded />
    </MediaTypes> 
</MultiMediaShow>
```

In the above example, I assume 2 "known" MediaTypes `SomeType` and `AnotherType`, comming from 2 plugin assemblies. The third type (`UnknownTypeFromPluginNotLoaded`) is unknown.

I'm already able to deserialize such unknown objects, but struggle with the serialization. In my aplication, I've the following code so far:

```
// To be implemented / subclassed by plugin assembly types
public abstract class MediaType
{
}

public class UnknownMediaType : MediaType 
{
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XmlElement[] UnknownChildElements;
    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttibute[] UnknownAttributes;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string XmlTagName;   // stores the xml element tag name in the original document
}

[XmlRoot("MultimediaShow")]
public class MultimediaShow
{
    public List<MediaType> MediaTypes = new List<MediaType>();
}
```

When deserializing this with `XmlSerializer`, I use the event `UnknownElement` and manually insert an `UnknownMediaType` element into `show.MediaTypes`:

```
void HandleUnknownElements(Show show, List<XmlElementEventArgs> unknownElementEvents, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides)
{
    // add a root attribute to UnknownMediaType
    XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
    XmlRootAttribute xmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute(e.Element.Name);
    attrs.XmlRoot = xmlRoot;
    XmlAttributeOverrides o = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    o.Add(typeof(UnknownMediaObject), attrs);

    // use a new XmlSerializer and a memory stream for deserializting the object as UnknownMediaType.
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UnknownMediaType), o);
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(e.Element, true));
        doc.Save(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        try
        {
            // deserialize the object, store the XML element name and insert it into the chapter
            UnknownMediaType t = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream) as UnknownMediaObject;
            t.XmlTagName = e.Element.Name;
            show.MediaTypes.Add(t);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            //return objectType.IsByRef ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        }
    }
}
```

The **BIG BIG** problem is that such an event doesn't seem to be available when serializing an object. What I get as output (not very surpising) is:

```
<MultiMediaShow>
    <MediaTypes>
        <SomeType />
        <SomeType />
        <AnotherType /> 
        <UnknownMediaType />    // !!!! was 'UnknownTypeFromPluginNotLoaded' !!!!
    </MediaTypes> 
</MultiMediaShow>
```

However, this is obviously not the same as what I've deserialized. So the question is, how would I best solve this problem?!?!

All help highly appreciated!!

Cheers,
Felix

---

**UPDATE**

I was wondering if it is possible to generate classes programmatically that derive from `UnknownMediaType` and have the class name taken from the `UnknownMediaType.XmlTagName`. Or, alternativly, to have an attribute for specifying the XML tag name of a class??

Cheers,
Felix

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I implemented some working solution based on building types dynamically. So far, it's doing what I want. The only downside I see at the moment is that I create them into the current app domain, so I can't unload them (e.g. if a new show is loaded or if the plugins would be made available at runtime).

Here's my code:

```
    void HandleUnknownElements(Show show, List<XmlElementEventArgs> unknownElementEvents, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides)
    {
        foreach (XmlElementEventArgs e in unknownElementEvents)
        {
            // (1) Dynamically create a type that simply inherits from UnknownMediaType 

            AssemblyName assName = new AssemblyName("Show Dynamic Type " + e.Element.Name + " Assembly");
            AssemblyBuilder assBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder modBuilder = assBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assBuilder.GetName().Name);

            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType(e.Element.Name, TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(UnknownMediaType));
            Type objectType = typeBuilder.CreateType();


            // (2) Add a root attribute to the type as override

            XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
            XmlRootAttribute xmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute(e.Element.Name);
            attrs.XmlRoot = xmlRoot;
            XmlAttributeOverrides o = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
            o.Add(objectType, attrs);


            // (3) Use a memory stream for creating a temporary XML document that will be deserialized

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(e.Element, true));
                doc.Save(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;


                // (4) Deserialize the object using an XmlSerializer and add it

                try
                {
                    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType, o);
                    UnknownMediaType t = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream) as UnknownMediaType;
                    show.MediaTypes.Add(t);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Would be glad if you'd post any issues with this and your concerns...

Cheers,
Felix

Answer (score 1):

See whether you can implement the **[IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)** interface for your root class.

From MSDN:

> There are two reasons to implement
>   this interface. The first is to
>   control how your object is serialized
>   or deserialized by the XmlSerializer.
>   For example, you can chunk data into
>   bytes instead of buffering large data
>   sets, and also avoid the inflation
>   that occurs when the data is encoded
>   using Base64 encoding. To control the
>   serialization, implement the ReadXml
>   and WriteXml methods to control the
>   XmlReader and XmlWriter classes used
>   to read and write the XML. For an
>   example of this, see How To: Chunk
>   Serialized Data.
>
> The second reason is to be able to
>   control the schema. To enable this,
>   you must apply the
>   XmlSchemaProviderAttribute to the
>   serializable type, and specify the
>   name of the static member that returns
>   the schema. See the
>   XmlSchemaProviderAttribute for an
>   example.
>
> A class that implements the interface
>   must have a parameterless constructor.
>   This is a requirement of the
>   XmlSerializer class

Comment: Yeah, I thought about IXmlSerializable. The problem is that my actual model is much more complex than what I used for illustration above. So, implementing the entire serialization of the MultimediaShow by hand would be horrible. Plus, whenever I change the model, I'd need to change the serialization code as well -- a very dangerous fact, since this is easily forgotten (particularly with several developers at work). Would it be possible to combine both IXmlSerializable and XmlSerializer in a smart way that allows me to just serialize the UnknownMediaType objects by hand?

Comment: How about using `System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder` for creating a new type at runtime that derives from UnknownMediaType and with the class name identically to the xml tag name? Wouldn't this work?

Comment: Is it possible that ThirdPartyMediaTypy will be pretty complex structure or they are stricted by some rules?

Comment: no, plugin types can be whatever they want. Not restricted at all. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a customer serializer. It is more work than using the xmlserializer, but gives you full control. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'll have a look at it. How would I use custom serialization with XML? Does the XmlSerializer check for this interface?

Comment: How about using `System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder` for creating a new type at runtime that derives from UnknownMediaType and with the class name identically to the xml tag name? Wouldn't this work?